# Django Async (uvicorn) is very slow

Tags: django, performance, gunicorn, uvicorn

I have a boilerplate app and was playing around with Django Async(planning to add some GraphQL + subscriptions) and made a benchmark that shocked me.

Gunicorn with async worker uvicorn is much more slower than gthread.

Async
Code:

```
async def my_async_view(request):
   return JsonResponse(
    {"async accounts": "Test"},
    status=200,
)
```

Gunicorn Async command:

```
gunicorn --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker banking_api.asgi --workers=8 --threads=2
```

---

Sync Code

```
def my_sync_view(request):
   return JsonResponse(
    {"sync accounts": "Test"},
    status=200,
)
```

Gunicorn Sync command:

```
gunicorn banking_api.wsgi --workers=8 --threads=2
```

---

Benchmark results:

Async:

```
Running 30s test @ http://localhost:8000/test/
  12 threads and 50 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    57.72ms   75.82ms   1.08s    97.25%
    Req/Sec    81.90     44.42   232.00     81.61%
  29007 requests in 30.05s, 8.08MB read
Requests/sec:    965.41
```

Sync:

```
Running 30s test @ http://localhost:8000/test/
  12 threads and 50 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    24.26ms   44.37ms 865.76ms   92.37%
    Req/Sec   281.56    146.56     0.89k    66.32%
  100051 requests in 30.08s, 30.25MB read
Requests/sec:   3326.37
```

What is happening? Why the difference of Requests/sec of 3326.37 (sync) vs 965.41 (async) ?
Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post a more complete example?  there might be some differences in the "middle ware" that's affecting things.